# Right Alt + Letter for Umlaut does not work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I used to be able to type an umlaut U (ü) under the English (United States) International Keyboard. To do so, I simply had to use the `Right Alt` key while pressing the letter `u`. This also worked for ö, and ä.

However, recently I can't to do that anymore: to type ü, I now have to press `Right Alt + y`.

I then looked into the layout of the ENG-INTL keyboard, and would you know it, `Right Alt + y` actually corresponds to the [actual layout](http://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html) of the keyboard for ü. This is so unintuitive to me, and I couldn't care less about other diacritics.

**Which begs the question: how on earth was I able to simply use `Right Alt + u` for the umlaut ü? And how do I get that back?**

PS. I know that a few times in the past, I accidentally switched to the "actual" layout (with `Right Alt + y` for ü) by pressing some kind of hotkey combinations. However, I always was able to switch back to "my" desired layout, perhaps by accidentally pressing the combination one more time.

This time, however, I couldn't find a way to switch back anymore, no matter how many times I have smashed my keyboard hoping for a miracle. Any help from you is dearly appreciated (before I lose my mind completely).

Comment: I suppose one thing you could do was possibly map it out yourself. the code to do so is ALT 0252

Comment: Would a workaround like an AutoHotkey script be an option for you? Have a look at my related question, it has some excellent answers: http://superuser.com/q/677727/255644